# Recent loanwords from other languages than English?

Tags: anglais, emprunts

Are there in French recent loanwords from languages other than English? By "recent", I mean the past 50 years or so.

Comment: The only one I would date as "recent" is [wesh](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/wech) from Aarabic. There are probably more.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question somewhat? 50 years is a long time. There have probably been thousands of new non English loanwords in food, culture, science, etc.

Comment: @guillaume31 Thousands? Could you give, say, five of them?

Comment: @user1387866 Graffito gave more than a dozen for food and sports only

Comment: @guillaume31 Yes, he did. What Graffito answered is exactly what I was asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In culinary field, [Le petit Robert](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Petit_Robert) added a lot of dishes names since 1967.

[Examples :](https://boulanger.recherche.usherbrooke.ca/document-article-boulanger_malkowska_2008) *basmati, carpaccio, falafel, houmous, maki, margarita, mojito, panini, plancha, surimi, tiramisu*.

Sports and Martial arts examples : *Bouzkachi* (Afghanistan), *Capoeira* (Brasil), *Krav-maga* (Israel).